# Fix gap from border-bottom none

Tags: css

I have a `<a>` tag with `border: 1px solid #CCC; border-bottom:none;` style and it's leaves a tiny gap, please look at the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EwkpD) result to see what I mean. This gap appears left from login tab if the login tab is active or right from register tab if register tab is active.

HTML:

```
<div id="w-login">
    <div id="login">
        <menu id="tabs"> <a id="tab-signin" class="tab-active"><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i>Login</a><a id="tab-signup"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i>Register</a>

        </menu>
        <div id="signin">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username" class="control-label col-1">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control col-2" id="si-username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="control-label col-1">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control col-2" id="si-password">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" id="si-submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="signup">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username" class="control-label col-1">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control col-2" id="su-username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="control-label col-1">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control col-2" id="su-password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="control-label col-1">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control col-2" id="su-email">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary" id="su-submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#container:before {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -3px;
}
#w-login {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 5px;
}
#login {
}
#signin, #signup {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-top: none;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
#signup {
    display: none;
}
#tabs {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom: none;
}
#tabs a {
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#tabs .tab-active {
}
#tab-signin.tab-active {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
#tab-signup.tab-active {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
}
.col-1 {
    width: 28%;
}
.col-2 {
    width: 70%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.form-horizontal .form-group {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.btn {
    width: 99%;
}
.fa {
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Note: the rest of the CSS styles come from Bootstrap

JS/jQuery:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#tab-signin').click(function(){
       $('#signup').hide(); 
       $('#signin').show();
       switchTab();
    });
    $('#tab-signup').click(function(){
       $('#signin').hide(); 
       $('#signup').show();
       switchTab();
    });
});

function switchTab(){
    $('#tabs a').toggleClass('tab-active');
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here. If Codepen ever disappears, this question will be useless to people viewing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following approach.

I would take advantage of the fact that in your mark-up the two tab elements, 
`#tab-signin` and `#tab-signup`, are children of the `menu#tabs` element.

That being the case, I would place the left, top and right borders on the `#tabs` element
and remove the left/top and top/right borders on the two children elements (`#tab-signin` and `#tab-signup` respectively).

The CSS for `#tabs` would look like:

```css
#tabs{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

To style the `.tab-active` cases, I would create two specific rules for the sign-in and the sign-up tabs, for the right/bottom and the bottom/left borders respectively:

```css
#tabs .tab-active{
}

#tab-signin.tab-active{
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
}

#tab-signup.tab-active{
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/By4g5/

The problem you noticed earlier is not really a browser bug.  The CSS specification does not specify exactly how browsers are to draw the corners of borders (the joints), so you are at the mercy of the browser for that particular design detail.

My approach is to avoid the problem by taking full advantage of the HTML mark-up in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try floats but a quick fix could be negative margins...

```
#tabs{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0px 0px -1px 0px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/minLB)

EDIT: inline blocks side effects, something to read ;)

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: +1 For the extra information. Another method would be `position:relative; top:1px`.

Comment: What is the issue, Nit? The change sucks up the content to remove the 1px break in the border on the side. If you are going to downvote, please add a comment explaining why.

Comment: @Nit Did i miss something?

Comment: It's a ridiculously bad solution, as is your floating recommendation.

Comment: @Nit I would love to see your "Good" solution :)

Comment: I'm sure many people would enjoy outsourcing all of their work to SO.

Comment: The problem is that the border on one side is pushing down the content. There are other solutions, but this is absolutely not a "ridiculously bad solution", Prashank. Granted you could add more information about WHY it works. But that is a comment on your answer, not the solution method.

Comment: Allow me to expand on why this is a bad solution: it makes the assumption the layout is final, that it won't change in the future. But that's very rarely the case with today's web media. This means that once there comes a need to practically use margin and/or padding on that element a whole lot more will need to be changed rather than fixing this small problem properly right off the bat.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be if set a transparent border on class `.tab-active`.

just using `border transparent` .

```
#tabs .tab-active{
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Chec the **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cutgf)**.

Comment: I've checked and a small white space were removed. should I've share a screenshot then you will agree ?

Comment: This doesn't hold for Firefox 25, for example.

Comment: I am sorry I always keep update my browser. checked in latest IE11 FF29, chrome35.  And its working..

Comment: You know your code is fragile when it doesn't work consistently even across the last few releases of Firefox. Allow me to explain further, if this criticism doesn't seem relevant: on the open web, the majority of users use an out-dated browser. While features like auto-updating help remedy this it's still a truth web developers need to keep in mind. Your code should perform reasonably well and provide a graceful fallback for older browsers (back to a reasonable point).

Comment: I am only worried about IE older versions. I assuming FF and chrome are updated automatically. so if you facing this problem in IE older version then post a message otherwise no need to discuss on this topic further. Also to criticize other people work will only consider If you can come-up with better solution.